# Como manipular UTF-8 no Lua

Tags: lua, utf-8, utf8-decode

Como trabalhar com uma string composta da codificação UTF-8 no Lua?

Como por exemplo:

- obter código de um caractere numa string pela sua índice;
- codificar códigos de caracteres, algo tipo `string.char(...códigos)` ou `('').char`.

Quais são as possíveis maneiras?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sendo a versão 5.3 (apesar que não entendo muito) pode usar o módulo [`utf8`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.5) e terá as funções:

- [`utf8.char`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-utf8.char)
- [`utf8.charpattern`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-utf8.charpattern)
- [`utf8.codepoint`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-utf8.codepoint)
- [`utf8.codes`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-utf8.codes)
- [`utf8.len`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-utf8.len)
- [`utf8.offset`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-utf8.offset)

---

Também existe um módulo [starwing/luautf8](https://github.com/starwing/luautf8) que possibilita ter algumas funções a mais (o autor afirma ter testado com Lua 5.2.3, Lua 5.3.0 and LuaJIT).

Para instalar use o comando (se tiver luarocks):

```
luarocks install luautf8
```

E chame assim no seu script para evitar conflito com as funções nativas:

```
local utf8 = require 'lua-utf8'
```

Se não tiver o luarocks pode tentar compilar manualmente este arquivo https://github.com/starwing/luautf8/blob/master/lutf8lib.c.

Algumas funções são `utf8.byte`, `utf8.char`, `utf8.find`, `utf8.gmatch`, `utf8.gsub`, `utf8.len`, `utf8.lower`, `utf8.match`, `utf8.reverse`, `utf8.sub` e `utf8.upper`.

Answer (score 4):

Para acrescentar, na versão 5.3 há uma síntaxe especial para codificar o código de um caractere (quase igual ao utf8.char):

```
local chr = '\u{código}';
```

*código*: um código hexadecimal.

A diferença é que a síntaxe só codifica um caractere de vez e só funciona com strings onde o caractere \ representa *escape*.

E aqui vem outra biblioteca [utf8 no GitHub](https://github.com/Stepets/utf8.lua) que não precisa ser compilada ou instalada nativamente.

Comment: Entendi, fica bem mais fácil +1